# Using JSON Data to Populate a Google Map with Database Objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, google-maps

I'm revising this question after reading the resources mentioned in the original answers and working through implementing it.

I'm using the google maps api to integrate a map into my Rails site. I have a markets model with the following columns: ID, name, address, lat, lng.

On my markets/index view, I want to populate a map with all the markets in my markets table.  I'm trying to output @markets as json data, and that's where I'm running into problems.  I have the basic map displaying, but right now it's just a blank map.  I'm following the tutorials very closely, but I can't get the markers to generate dynamically from the json.  Any help is much appreciated!

Here's my setup:

Markets Controller:

```
def index
   @markets = Market.filter_city(params[:filter])
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render :json => @market}
     format.xml  { render :xml => @market }
  end
end
```

Markets/index view:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=GOOGLE KEY REDACTED, BUT IT'S THERE" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markets = <%= @markets.to_json %>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    google.load("maps", "2.x");
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div> 
</body>
```

Public/javascripts/application.js:

```
function initialize() {   
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible() && typeof markets != 'undefined') {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.7371, -73.9903), 13);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());

function createMarker(latlng, market) {
  var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
  var html="<strong>"+market.name+"</strong><br />"+market.address;
  GEvent.addListener(marker,"click", function() {
    map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, html);
  });
  return marker;
}

var bounds = new GLatLngBounds;
for (var i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
  var latlng=new GLatLng(markets[i].lat,markets[i].lng)
  bounds.extend(latlng);
  map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, markets[i]));
}
```

}
}

```
window.onload=initialize;  
window.onunload=GUnload;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@markets` instead of `@market` in `format.json { render :json => @market}` ?

Comment: don't you need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>` in Markets/index view?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're only looking for free resources, but the book [Advanced Rails Recipes](http://pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/advanced-rails-recipes) has a pretty good write up on this. You can get the source code from the Pragmatic Programmer's site (I'd recommend getting the book, too).

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took in creating a prototype was to not have the html version of the view be responsible for creating the map and placing the markers. What I did was use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html), jQuery, ajax and json. My page initially loads, then makes a request for the json (which would be a list of your markets). Once I have the json I create the map and add the markers with jQuery and the Google Maps API.

[Here's a good tutorial](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics) for getting started with jQuery and Google Maps.

**Edit:** here's how I'd simplify it to get started - once this is working then add the html and event stuff back in.

```
function createMarker(latlng, market) {
  return new GMarker(latlng);
}

$(function() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible() && typeof markets != 'undefined') {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.7371, -73.9903), 13);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());

    $(markers).each(function(i, obj) {
      var m = obj.market; // this *might* be var m = obj;
      var latlng = new GLatLng(m.lat, m.lng); // check m.lat and m.lng in FireBug
      map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, m));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Andy, based on the code I pasted in my revised question, could you give me any pointers on the json part of the process?

Comment: What part isn't working? The only thing I'd change is switching to jQuery's ready function. Drop the window.onload... and put your application JS inside of `$(document).ready(function() {  });`

Comment: More accurately, one point populates on the map, but it stays in a fixed spot on the screen and does not correlate to any of the markets in my database.  In other words, no matter how I move the map around or zoom in/out, the marker doesn't move.

Comment: I would just try to break it down piece by piece. It's a little involved so I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Andy, thanks for taking the time to post this code.  I kept getting js errors when trying to implement it - I have zero experience with js so I'm sure it was an issue on my end.  I ended up having a more experienced friend fix this for me and we had to do some funky stuff to get it working.  Still not sure what the core problem was.